# JavaScript ( числовое значение Infinity )

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер! Подскажите как может использоваться числовое значение Infinity??? для чего оно введено в JS?

Как бы с NaN вроде понятно, но Infinity...

Как понять 1 / 0 = Infinity, но 0 / 0 =  NaN

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: ну всё в рамках математики) если бесконечность и есть неопределённость. А вопрос то в чём?

Comment: Infinity - бесконечность, в js, это особенность деления на ноль, логично же, чем меньше делитель, тем больше результат, то есть 1 / 0 = бесконечность, а 0 / 0 = NaN, NaN по сути это ошибка математического исчисления, а применить Infinity, например можно сравнивать за ведома не известные числа (23423423 < Infinity) ведь Infinity всегда больше

Answer (score 1):

`Infinity` и `-Infinity` обозначают бесконечность и числа, которые слишком большие или маленькие, чтобы вместить в 64-битное число.

Например:

- `1 / 0 === Infinity`
- `1 / -0 === -Infinity`
- `1e1000 === Infinity`
- `-1/1e-1000 === -Infinity`

Answer (score 0):

**NaN** — специальное значение типа **Number**, для выражения **«не чисел»**, **«неопределенности»**. Может быть получено, например, как результат деления 0 на 0 (из курса матанализа помним, что это неопределенность, а деление других чисел на 0 — это бесконечность, для которой в JS есть значения Infinity).